# Integral the differential inequality

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f(r):\Bbb{R_+}\to \Bbb{R}_+$ be smooth monotone increasing function with $f(0) =0$ which satisfies the differential inequality :

$$f'(r) \ge (1/2C)f(r)^{1-\frac{1}{n}}\tag{*}$$

where $n\ge 1$, $C>0$. Is it possible to lower bound $f(R)$ by $(R /2nC)^n$?

I know the idea is try to get something like $f'\ge g'$ then inegrate on both side gets the result,but I have some technical difficulty in solving the differential equation (*) above.

Comment: What I mean is take some transformation $F(f(x)) = g(x)$ such that $g(x)$ satisfies the gronwall inequality. However I have no idea how to take such transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is true as long as $f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x>0$, but I guess this is given by your assumptions. First divide your differential inequality by $f^{1-\frac{1}{n}}$ (here $f\neq 0$ comes into play), which yields
$$f' f^{\frac{1}{n}-1} \geq \frac{1}{2C}.$$
Now we can integrate and obtain by the monotonicity of the integral
$$\int_0^Rf'(x) f^{\frac{1}{n}-1}(x) dx \geq \int_0^R\frac{1}{2C}dx = \frac{R}{2C}.$$
Now chain rule yields for the left hand side
$$\int_0^Rf'(x) f^{\frac{1}{n}-1}(x) dx = \int_0^R (n f(x)^{\frac{1}{n}})'\, dx =n f(R)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
Now solving the resulting inequality for $f(R)$ should yield your desired result.